# postgres container exited cannot restart because 'chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Permission denied'

Tags: postgresql, docker

If anyone could help me would be much appreciated. I'm running postgres container on centos machine where it runs with no problem for over a year already, and it suddenly exited for whatever reason. I tried to re start the container with `docker start` but it exited immediately with error `chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Permission denied`. I can't lose the data, so what would be the best way to solve this issue?

Here's my docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    container_name: garvan_rems_app
    environment:
      AUTHENTICATION: :oidc
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://db:5432/rems?user=rems&password=*****
      PORT: 3000
      PUBLIC_URL: <-URL->
      oidc-client-id: ***********************
      oidc-client-secret: *****************
      oidc-domain: *****.au.auth0.com
    image: garvan_rems_app
    mem_limit: 500m
    mem_reservation: 200m
    ports:
    - 0.0.0.0:3000:3000/tcp
  db:
    container_name: garvan_rems_db
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ***
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ******
    mem_reservation: 30m
    mem_limit: 150m
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
  auth0:
    container_name: garvan_rems_auth0
    image: <auth0 image name>
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:3333:3333"
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you please send your docker-compose.yml or dockerfile.yml with command which you have started your container